# Apache Mahout Naive Bayes Training size

Tags: mahout

I am training a data set which has 2 categories using the Naive Bayes algorithm.

I was wondering if the 2 categories need to have an equal amount in each for weightings on words to be distributed well, or is this not necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary, although each category should have enough samples to avoid overfitting.

Comment: only thing to add here is - are there any references to confirm this? or is this knowledge from experience?

Comment: Not knowledge from experience with Mahout (I've used it, but not its Naive Bayes implementation), but knowledge from experience. A NB model is learned based on the *frequency* of each feature within the training set, not on the absolute number of occurrences, and the model for each category is learned independently. Put simply, there's no way for the number of samples in one category to affect the probability estimates produced by the other category's model.

Comment: Incidentally, the classifiers which suffer if the class sizes differ tend to be the ones which are subject to overfitting, such as kNN and decision trees. NB, in contrast, is pleasantly resilient to overfitting (particularly with the use of pseudocounts) and doesn't care much about relative class sizes.